# Envio de SMS através de WebSite

Tags: php, asp, sms

Estou desenvolvendo um WebSite de delivery onde gostaria que quando o cliente finalizasse o pedido, fosse enviado um SMS para o celular dele.

Teria alguma forma (gratuita de preferencia, mas pode ser paga tambem) de fazer isso utilizando algum script asp, ou mais provavel em php?

**Obs:** O sistema é totalmente Web, ou seja, nenhuma integração com android, ios ou coisa do tipo, ele será utilizado no navegador normal de tais dispositivos.

Comment: conheço - e utilizo - o Zenvia. O mesmo fornece uma API com integração em várias linguagens, inclusive PHP (e se não me engano em ASP também). O endereço é http://zenvia.com.br. Caso se interessar me avise, que postarei um exemplo como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado vou dar uma olhada @Thiago.

Comment: @Marconi o a pergunta dele não tem nada a ver com a minha. O dele abre o sistema de SMS do próprio celular, o meu eu quero enviar o SMS sem nenhuma integração com o android ou cobrança do cliente.

Comment: Olá bruno, no caso eu marquei como dup baseado na sua pergunta *"Teria alguma forma (gratuita de preferencia, mas pode ser paga tambem) de fazer isso utilizando algum script asp, ou mais provavel em php?"*, enviar com modem 3g conectado no servidor é um exemplo de ser fazer isto, mas cada uma das respostas que estão linkadas a pergunta mostram maneiras diferentes, inclusive 2 se eu não me engano são serviços gratuitos ;)